# error in my code because of another method

Tags: java

the output should be 3 but I get error in the code , How to fix that?

```
public class Tetris {
        public static void add(int x, int y, int sum)
        {
         sum = x + y;
         return sum;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 1;
            int y = 2;
            int sum;
            add(sum); // sum cannot be resolved to a variable
            System.out.print(sum);

            }
        }
```

Comment: where did you declare it?

Comment: Please do not change the content of your question; it can invalidate answers that already exist.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below Code, it is working correctly

```
public class Tetris {
        public static int add(int x, int y)
        {
         int sum = x + y;
     return sum;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 1;
            int y = 2;
        int sum = 0;
            sum = add(x,y); 
            System.out.print(sum);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the variable `sum` in `main`, so it's undefined.  But even if you did define it, methods receive *copies* of the arguments passed in, so assigning a value to `sum` in `add` doesn't change a declared `sum` in `main`.  Instead, have `add` return the `sum`, and in `main`, assign the return value of `add` to `main`'s `sum`.

Comment: can you see the code please , I changed it , was that you meant?? thanks

Comment: No.  Please don't change your question; it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

> sum cannot be resolved to a variable

```
int sum;//You should declare sum variable
```

But there is no need of `sum` here.

```
System.out.print(add(x,y));
```

Next, change `add()` method return type to `int`

```
public static int add(int x, int y)
{
 int sum=x+y;
 return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `sum` through to the `add` method, but you have not declared it at all.  What you should do instead is this:

```
public class Tetris {
    public static int add(int x, int y)
    {
      int sum = x + y;
      return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        System.out.println(add(x,y)); // sum cannot be resolved to a variable


        }
    }
```

Comment: where should I put   System.out.print(sum);

Comment: It will print out the sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tetris{

    /*
     * Java passes references by value.
     * 
     * So you can't change the reference that gets passed in.
     */
    public static int sum = 0;

    public static void add(int x, int y) {
        sum = x + y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        add(x, y); // sum cannot be resolved to a variable
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

You never declared 'sum.' Also, you would not be able to change the value of sum by passing it in that way.